JSDOC Reference key of other type
How does one reference the key of another object within a @type or @typedef?
/**
 * @typedef {{name: {name: string}}} moo
 * @typedef {{name: moo.name}} moo2
 */

I would expect vscode to resolve moo2 as having structure {name: {name: string}}, but it does not.

You have to use the bracket notation:
/**
 * @typedef {{ name: moo["name"] }} moo2
 */

If you use TS flavored JSDoc and you need to reference a property of the same name, you can also use Pick:
/**
 * @typedef {Pick<moo, "name">} moo2 -> { name: { name: string }}
 */

